# Are media events atomic in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, events, html5-video, dom-events, atomic

I'm writing a web application. Multiple videos are playing, and when a video stops playing the ended event is captured. The piece of code that is called is like:

```
var nextVideoSrc = getNextSrc();
if(nextVideoSrc === null) {
    setVideoSrc(video, videoSrcs[index]);
    index = (index + 1) % videoSrcs.length;
} else
    setVideoSrc(video, videoSrcs[index]);
```

Basically, it looks for a new video url, and when no video url is found, it gets a video (url) from a pool (an Array of urls). As I stated, more than one video is playing at the same time. So my question is: when two video's throw the ended event at the same time, are these functions atomic? Because when that is not the case, the same index that is incremented could be used twice. For example, the first video uses `videoSrcs[index]` and the ended event from second video runs in between and uses same index.

Comment: Video ending events are not _atomic_ but I think you want to know if they're thread-safe. Answer is **yes** because JavaScript code is executed in a single thread (code for 2nd event won't be executed until code for 1st one - or any other executing code besides working threads - won't finish).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is completely single-threaded. Each time the stop event is fired it will placed on the `message queue`. There is an `event loop` which iteratively checks the `message queue` for new events and executes them `to completion` before moving on to the next.

The event loop resembles something like this:

```
while(queue.waitForMessage()){
  queue.processNextMessage();
}
```

This means you don't have to worry about events happening concurrently and your increments will always be handled sequentially.

[Here's a handy source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop) if you want to learn more about the JavaScript concurrency model.